# SimpleListFilter has no effect to admin form, Django 2.2.8

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm using Django 2.2.8. I have an entity "**AppSettings**" with such attributes as [*category: str, name: str, value: str, description: str*]. Pair [*category, name*] is unique. There're no foreign key relations.

Now I want to make an editable grid in admin page. And I want this grid to be filtered by categories in the right pane using **list_filter** property. I have following classes in admin.py:

```
class AppSetsListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Category'
    parameter_name = 'category'
    default_value = 'All'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        cats = set([v for v in AppSettings.objects.all().values_list('category', flat=True)])
        return sorted([(c, c) for c in cats], key=lambda c: c[0])

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if not self.value() or self.value() == 'All':
            return queryset
        return queryset.filter(category=self.value())


class AppSetsAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AppSettings
        fields = ['category', 'name', 'value', 'description']
        widgets = {
            'value': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'rows': '2', 'cols': '95'
                }
            )
        }


class AppSettingsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['category', 'name', 'value', 'description']
    search_fields = ['name', 'description']
    list_editable = ['value']
    list_display_links = ['category']
    list_filter = (AppSetsListFilter, )

    def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        return AppSetsAdminForm
```

I've got no error. "Value" cell is editable. It has 2-rows text area in. But no "filter" pane appear, although there're about 60 records displayed.

I thought there might be an issue with list_filter + list_editable OR list_filter + get_changelist_form. I removed this options but no filter (right) pane appears.

Comment: Right pane isn't rendered because of django-suit...

Answer (score 0):

Right pane isn't rendered because of django-suit.